# Convert data format with scores in a single colun

Tags: pandas, database-design, structure

Hello great community!

I have a table named Students having scores of students in multiple subjects stored in different columns. I want to convert it from having a single row for on student with multiple columns (showing scores across different subjects) to having multiple rows of the same student with a single column for Scores and a column named subject so that the data is stored for each subject in a different row.

Problem

[image: Problem]

Desired Format

[image: Desired Format]

I tried iterating rows through columns but didn't work.
Appreciate any help guys. Looking to solve it using Pandas

Comment: please take the tables in your pictures, and copy paste it in

Comment: but also have you heard of melting your data?

Comment: df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'name'], var_name='Subject', value_name='Score')

Comment: consider reading the documentation/doing a *bit* more searching before asking a question in the future, because this question has been asked many times before! https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html it tests people's patience to answer the same thing over and over